# Apache 2.4: Can I use variables for conditionals in requests?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache-config, apache-expression

## tl;dr

In NGINX, you can define variables and evaluate them in each request. I'm not possible to reproduce this in Apache v2.4. **Can I use variables for conditionals in requests at all?**

## What I want

`${docroot}/dev/api.php` contains an API, which should never be reached by direct access, but by location `/api` only.

1. user visits `example.org/dev/api.php` and get gets an error 404 or "Authorization required"
2. user visits `example.org./api/endpoint`, which falls back to /dev/api.php internally.

In NGINX, I can use a variable for this. If the user visits the location, the variable is TRUE, otherwise (e.g. direct access) it's false and he get's the error.

## Code

```
<VirtualHost *:8443>
    Define docroot /var/www/html/test
    Define fromAPI false # default is: no access
 
    ServerName    shop.example.org
    ServerAdmin   admin@example.org
    DocumentRoot  ${docroot}
    Protocols h2 http/1.1
 
    # that's the location of the API (there is no directory named "api")
    <Location /api>
        AllowOverride None
        Define fromAPI true # user has access
        FallbackResource /dev/api.php
    </Location>
 
    # The API code is living here.
    # When user visits it "${fromAPI} == false", it should end up in error 404.
    # When API visits it "${fromAPI} == true", the access should be granted.
    <Directory ${docroot}/dev>
        # <If "-T env('fromAPI')">
        # <If "-T env('fromAPI')">
        # <If "${fromAPI}">
        # <If "-T '${fromAPI}'">
            Redirect 404 /dev/
        </If>
    </Directory>
  
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.2 
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/privkey.pem
 
    # HTTP Strict Transport Security (mod_headers is required) (31536000 seconds)
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload"
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> # that's the location of the API (there is no directory named "api")
> <Location /api>
>     AllowOverride None
>     Define fromAPI true # user has access
>     FallbackResource /dev/api.php
> </Location>
>
> # The API code is living here.
> # When user visits it "${fromAPI} == false", it should end up in error 404.
> # When API visits it "${fromAPI} == true", the access should be granted.
> <Directory ${docroot}/dev>
>     # <If "-T env('fromAPI')">
>     # <If "-T env('fromAPI')">
>     # <If "${fromAPI}">
>     # <If "-T '${fromAPI}'">
>         Redirect 404 /dev/
>     </If>
> </Directory>
> ```

I'm not sure that this *pattern* would work, since `<Location>` sections are merged *after* `<Directory>` sections.

You could do this using mod_rewrite instead in the main `<Directory>` section for the `${docroot}`.

For example:

```
<Directory ${docroot}>
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride None

    RewriteEngine On

    # Block direct access to "/dev/"
    RewriteRule ^dev/ - [R=404]

    # Rewrite "/api/<something>" to "/dev/api.php"
    RewriteRule ^api/. dev/api.php [END]
</Directory>
```

I used mod_rewrite, instead of `FallbackResource` in order to specifically target requests for `/api/<something>` only.

The `END` flag prevents all further processing of the rewrite engine in this context. (So the preceding rule that blocks access does not need a condition to prevent blocking the rewritten request.)